# Storing MySQL Username/Password In Config File

Tags: mysql, encryption, wamp, credentials

I have a web app that will connect to a MySQL database and I want to store the connection credentials encrypted in a config file in the web root. I have seen a number of articles and posts on what to do, but can't find any instruction on HOW to do it. The app is run on a WAMP Server on Azure.

Comment: Is encryption necessary or is it a "just to be safe" kind of measure because you could just prevent your configuration files to be served via your webserver.

Comment: Encrypting the credentials provides no real security benefit, and an (albeit slight) performance overhead. In order for your web server to run, it needs to access the plaintext credentials, which means that the keys for decrypting the credentials need to be stored somewhere an attacker can get to them if they breach your server. Thus, you gain no added security.

Comment: It's better practice to store the credentials above the web root so they can't be accessed externally at all, but if you really need to have them at or under the web root, you can blacklist access to the file with an htaccess directive.